# How can I reuse functions across classes

Tags: python, oop

I have a few functions I'd like to reuse. This isn't my EXACT example but it is functionally similar.

For example, we'll say I have a bunch of python lists of integers that live in different classes that are each their own file. ListClassA.py, ListClassB.py, ListClassC.py.

I want to get averages for all those classes. I could make a nice little function in every single class that says sum the list and divide it by the length. What I'd like to do is make a new class that can do all my nice little list functions (average, max value, etc) so I can just call listFunctions.average(list). How can I call my new class from my existing classes?

Comment: You don't need a class at all. `average` et al. can just be functions defined in a module.

Comment: Also consider not using one file per class. There is just one language in the world that forces this on the user - Java. Python doesn't, and it's for the better. It allows to group classes and functions belonging to each other into one module, and possiby only break it up if it becomes unwieldy large.

Comment: If you really need a class-based solution, make your classes inherit from a base class that contains the sharable functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can `import` the new class

```
from new_file import listFunctions
```

Then you can use `listFunctions.average(list)`

Comment: Do not use `list` as a name in Python.